# No video with supported format and MIME type found in Firefox when print ( CTRL+P )

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, printing

I have following code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I am opening the HTML page in Firefox. Its playing normally. I am trying to print the page using browser print (CTRL + P). In print print preview it gives the preview properly but, When I print it it is giving " No video with supported format and MIME type found ".

The same is working fine in Chrome.

How to print the video preview in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I think the " No video with supported format and MIME type found " came from the default content of `<video>` tag. I think u need to store the video image preview separately, call it with `<img>` but dont display it. Only display it when css `@media` is `print`.

Well thats as far as i know